# How to expand the tree view in protractor tests. Below is the code snippet

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

Below is the code snippet. The code represents one item and I have multiple of these. All these are distinguished by **ng-reflect-index**. I want to write a test case by expanding these nodes one by one but could not expand the node by using protractor. I am able to go till **ng-reflect-index** by using css function (**element(by.css('[ng-reflect-index="1"]'))**). Now i would like to click on the span class `<span class="toggle-children-wrapper ng-star-inserted toggle-children-wrapper-collapsed">` would be really thankful if anyone can help me in fixing this.

```
<tree-node ng-reflect-node="[object Object]" ng-reflect-index="0" ng-reflect-templates="[object Object]" class="ng-star-inserted">
    <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-mobx-autorun": null
}--><!---->
      <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div class="tree-node-level-1 tree-node ng-star-inserted tree-node-active tree-node-focused tree-node-collapsed">

        <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><tree-node-drop-slot ng-reflect-node="[object Object]" ng-reflect-drop-index="0" class="ng-star-inserted">
    <div class="node-drop-slot" ng-reflect-tree-allow-drop="function () { [native code] }">
    </div>
  </tree-node-drop-slot>

        <tree-node-wrapper ng-reflect-node="[object Object]" ng-reflect-index="0" ng-reflect-templates="[object Object]">
      <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div class="node-wrapper ng-star-inserted" style="padding-left: 0px;">
        <tree-node-expander ng-reflect-node="[object Object]">
    <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-mobx-autorun": null
}--><!---->
      <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}-->
<span class="toggle-children-wrapper ng-star-inserted toggle-children-wrapper-collapsed">

        <span class="toggle-children"></span>
      </span>
      <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->

  </tree-node-expander>
        <div class="node-content-wrapper node-content-wrapper-active node-content-wrapper-focused" ng-reflect-tree-allow-drop="function (element, $event) {
 " draggable="true" ng-reflect-dragged-element="[object Object]" ng-reflect-tree-drag-enabled="true">

          <tree-node-content ng-reflect-node="[object Object]" ng-reflect-index="0" ng-reflect-template="[object Object]">
  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet-context": "[object Object]",
  "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet": "[object Object]"
}-->
      <span _ngcontent-c5="" class="ui-treenode-parent ng-star-inserted"></span>
      <span _ngcontent-c5="" title="Title" class="ng-star-inserted">Assets</span>
      <span _ngcontent-c5="" class="pull-right ng-star-inserted">(7)</span>

  </tree-node-content>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet-context": "[object Object]"
}-->

    </tree-node-wrapper>

        <tree-node-children ng-reflect-node="[object Object]" ng-reflect-templates="[object Object]">
    <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-mobx-autorun": null
}--><!---->
      <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-animate-speed": "true",
  "ng-reflect-animate-acceleration": "1.2",
  "ng-reflect-is-enabled": "true",
  "ng-reflect-is-open": "false"
}-->

  </tree-node-children>
        <tree-node-drop-slot ng-reflect-node="[object Object]" ng-reflect-drop-index="1">
    <div class="node-drop-slot" ng-reflect-tree-allow-drop="function () { [native code] }">
    </div>
  </tree-node-drop-slot>
      </div>
      <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet-context": "[object Object]"
}-->

    </tree-node>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as `git`?

Comment: What is your question... "I want to write a test case"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select that element and click it:

```
element(by.css('toggle-children-wrapper.ng-star-inserted.toggle-children-wrapper-collapsed')).click()
```

Comment: just add "." at the start of CSS.

Thanks for your answer. :)